# NETLOGO: Making network with exact number of links

Tags: hyperlink, nodes, netlogo

I need to do the network when agents will be connected with links and i want it make so that there will be exact number (variable) of links going from each agent. Lets say for example that i want 3 links going from each agent to another. No more, no less. I was trying to use this code:

```
let num-links (links * number) / 2 
  while [count links < num-links ]
  [
ask one-of turtles
[
  let choice (min-one-of (other turtles with [not link-neighbor? myself])
               [distance myself])
  if choice != nobody [ create-link-with choice ]
]
]
```

Where "number" is the number of nodes and "links" is number of links i want to go from each agent- But this code unfortunately works so that "links" is really just an average degree of node. So if I want 3 links, i could get all agent (except for example two) with 3 links going from them, but one of them would have only 1 link and another 5 (average is 3 then). Is there some way How to do it.

And is there some way how to do it so that each "link" would be actually two directed links, one going from the node and one going to the node?

And one last question. I want to give this links a variable, but i need to do it so that sum of these variables from each agent is exactly 100 (as percents).

Any help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried using create-links-with ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetLogo Efficient way to create fixed number of links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967388/netlogo-efficient-way-to-create-fixed-number-of-links)

Comment: King-ink: I did, but problem with that is that it can make link to agent which already has fixed number of links.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I create a fixed degree network for a small network (easy to understand)

```
to make-legal
  create-turtles 100 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  let target-degree 5
  while [ min [ count my-links ] of turtles < target-degree ]
  [ ask links [die]
    makeNW-Lattice target-degree
  ]
end

to makeNW-Lattice [DD]
  ask turtles
  [ let needed DD - count my-links
    if needed > 0
    [ let candidates other turtles with [ count my-links < DD ]
      create-links-with n-of min (list needed count candidates) candidates
    ]
  ]
end
```

See [NetLogo Efficient way to create fixed number of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967388/netlogo-efficient-way-to-create-fixed-number-of-links) for more efficient methods for larger networks.

Please ask separate questions for separate issues

**UPDATE** to ensure all nodes have required degree, in response to comment

Based on the following code, the basic generator does a `legal` network a little under 50% of the time. Therefore I simply threw the original code in a while loop and regenerated if not legal. This is not a good solution for larger networks, but is a reasonable hack.

```
to setup
  let mins (list 0 0 0 0 0 0)
  repeat 100
  [ ask turtles [die]
    ask links [die]
    makeNW-lattice
    let this-min min [ count my-links ] of turtles
    set mins replace-item this-min mins (item this-min mins + 1)
  ]
  print mins
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use it. Any idea how to get variable on links so that sum of varibales going from one node is always 100?

Comment: please ask separate question - SO is designed to construct a Q&A database so that people with the same question can find the answer. This requires separate questions with meaningful titles

Comment: Okay so I tried it and it actually doesnt work. Sometime all the nodes have same number of links going from them (lets say 5), but sometimes, there are nodes with less then 5 links. I even had one with no links at all. How is that possible?

Yeah sry, my bad with question. I didnt read last sentence of your answer before.

Comment: Because the nodes are asked in random order. Sometimes this means that the last node asked still needs edges but only has itself to link with. You could add a rewire procedure so that if there's no nodes available, it breaks an existing link, or if it's low probability for a bad result (depends on number of nodes and target degree) recreate from scratch if it happens to fail.

Comment: Oh, I see. Any idea how to do it? I am really a rookie progammer and i didnt know, that it will be so difficult to make something so easy like a network with fixed degree of nodes.

Comment: So i try to usee updated version, but unfortunately, it has problem with while procedure. Netlogo says: "WHILE expected this input to be a TRUE/FALSE block, but got a TRUE/FALSE instead".

Comment: sorry, hadn't tested it. try now

Comment: This unfortunately doesnt work eaither. I tells me that makenw-lattice expected 1 input. But not sure what "DD" stand for there. Cause if I remove it, i get pass it, but then it has problem with "makenw-lattice target degree". Says it expect command on target degree.

Comment: works for me. did you actually copy the code or did you (mis)type it instead? you need to run the procedure `make-legal`, which calls the other procedure. DD is to pass the degree from the calling procedure to the called procedure.